# C++ Winapi - Get Directory (path) identifier

Tags: c++, winapi, path, directory, identifier

I'm using Winapi's function `SHBrowseForFolder` and I need to set a default folder for browsing. To achieve that, I need to get the desired default folder's "PIDL". I can get the "PIDL" using this function: `SHGetFolderLocation(hwnd, nCSIDL, NULL, NULL, &pidlRoot);` but as you can see, the **second** parameter is another identifier "nCSIDL" (type int).

How can I get a path's indentifier by path (LPCSTR)?

This is my code:

```
TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
BROWSEINFO bInfo;
HWND hwnd = ObPanelAPI::GetPanelHandleByName("*Current");
bInfo.hwndOwner = hwnd;
bInfo.pszDisplayName = szDir;
bInfo.lpszTitle = "Seleccionar directorio"; //Dialog title
bInfo.ulFlags = 0 ;
bInfo.lpfn = NULL;
bInfo.lParam = 0;
bInfo.iImage = -1;

//Default folder set
LPITEMIDLIST pidlRoot = NULL;

//*******I NEED TO GET nCSIDL HERE********

SHGetFolderLocation(hwnd, nCSIDL, NULL, NULL, &pidlRoot);
bInfo.pidlRoot = pidlRoot; 

LPITEMIDLIST lpItem = SHBrowseForFolder(&bInfo);
```

Comment: Stupid MS magic numbers:(( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You want to resolve the CSIDL (constant special item ID list) value from a path?

Comment: @Emil Okay, as you say those numbers are constants that make reference to system-defined folders. I don't get this, how I'm supposed to get a folder identifier so? :s

Comment: Well, I have never heard about someone needing to do that. Why do you need the identifiers? To see if a path is a "special folder"?

Comment: @Emil - OP wants to start browsing folders in a consistent place across Windows versions.  That means using th eshell calls to find out the paths to the users' appdata folder, or whatever, on whatever continually-changing Windows filesystem it's currently running on.  That means finding out the Constant Pain In The Ass number.

Comment: AHA! http://www.installmate.com/support/im9/using/symbols/functions/csidls.htm

Comment: @Emil I'm just trying to set a default folder for the "folder browsing dialog".  The structure's member that defines the default folder is type "LPITEMIDLIST". I can get that type with the function "SHGetFolderLocation" but that function needs as a parameter a folder's identifier, this is a joke :/

Comment: OK "How can I get a path's indentifier by path (LPCSTR)?" got me asking.

Comment: Note that CSIDL's are deprecated.  Instead of Constant Pain In The Ass numbers, you should now use Gruesome GUIDs, AKA KNOWNFOLDERID values.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid 'this is a joke' yes, and a painful one at that.  The magic numbers were a bad joke, the magic GUIDs are worse:(

Comment: This is a strange thread. CSIDLs and KNOWNFOLDERIDs are constant values, they never change even though the actual path on disk they refer to might. So if you want to start in, say, the profile folder, you use `CSIDL_PROFILE` or `FOLDERID_Profile` and the appropriate function to convert those to a PIDL. The values are all listed in the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm using Winapi's function `SHBrowseForFolder` and I need to set a default folder for browsing. To achieve that, I need to get the desired default folder's "PIDL".

First, you need to differentiate something here.  `BROWSEINFO` has a `pidlRoot` field, which specifies the top-most folder that the browse dialogs displays.  A user cannot select items above that folder.  This is NOT the same thing as a "default folder", which is just the folder that is initially selected within the chosen root when the dialog appears.

To set a "default folder", you actually do not *need* a PIDL, you can use a path string instead (the dialog accepts both).  Assign a pointer to the path string to the `BROWSEINFO.lParam` field and provide a callback function in the `BROWSEINFO.lpfn` field.  Inside the callback, when it receives the `BFFM_INITIALIZED` notification, it can send the dialog a `BFFM_SETSELECTION` message, setting the `wParam` parameter to TRUE and setting the `lParam` parameter to the path string pointer.  This is documented on MSDN:

[BFFCALLBACK function pointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762598.aspx)

> BFFM_SETSELECTION
> Specifies the path of a folder to select. The path can be specified as a string or a PIDL.

Now, with that said, the `BROWSEINFO.pidlRoot` field requires a PIDL, and the `BFFM_SETSELECTION` message does accept a PIDL as input, so...

> I can get the "PIDL" using this function: `SHGetFolderLocation(hwnd, nCSIDL, NULL, NULL, &pidlRoot);` but as you can see, the **second** parameter is another identifier "nCSIDL" (type int).

That function is for retrieving PIDLs for special folders that are pre-defined by Microsoft, like Documents, AppData, User Profiles, etc.  These are identified by constant `CSIDL` values (and `KNOWNFOLDERID` values on Vista+) which are consistent on every Windows version, though the particular paths may differ from one system to another based on user configuration.

> How can I get a path's indentifier by path (LPCSTR)?

There are a few different ways:

1. [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775090.aspx).  Call [`SHGetDesktopFolder()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175.aspx) to get the `IShellFolder` for the Shell namespace root, and then call its `ParseDisplayName()` to parse the path.
2. [`SHParseDisplayName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236.aspx).  Similar to above, but with some additional options available.  Do be aware of the following note in the documentation, though:

   > You should call this function from a background thread. Failure to do so could cause the UI to stop responding.
3. [`ILCreateFromPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378420.aspx).  However, it has been observed that `ILCreateFromPath()` does not always return the same PIDLs that `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`/`SHParseDisplayName()` return, that sometimes that difference can cause things like `SHBrowseForFolder()` to behave incorrectly.  I have not personally experienced this, but other people claim they have.  You will just have to try it for yourself.